# How can I display a store value to a pannel? using EXTJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have data.xml file as follow

```
<root>
 <tag2>
   <key>12</key>
   <spec>15</spec>
 </tag2>
</root>
```

I want to display that key value and spec value on a panel window, here is the code I have, but I stuck at displaying. How can I display it out?

```
Ext.define('tag2',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{name: 'key', type: 'float'},
        {name: 'spec', type: 'float'}]
});

var tag2Store= Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
    model: 'tag2',
    autoLoad:true,
    proxy:{
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'data.xml',
        reader:{
            type: 'xml',
            record: 'tag2'
        }
    }
});



Ext.create('Ext.Window',{
    title: 'tag2',
    width: 400,
    height:500,
    x:400,
    y:300,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    store: tag2Store,
    hidden: false,
    maximizable: true,
    layout: 'fit',
    id: 'tag2',
    html: 'key = , spec = '
});
```

right at the html

```
html: 'key = , spec = '
```

I want 
     html: 'key = 12 , spec = 15 '

But I don't know what to do here

Thanks

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: I'm using the latest version. Thanks

Comment: was the below answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You would use the tpl property to provide a template for the data that you want rendered.

See the Template docs on how to use it:  http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate

Also window does not have a store property that it knows what to do with. You need to apply the data to the template yourself if you are using a window component. Otherwise you can use a DataView component : http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.view.View